# Change parameter to a boolean value in python

Tags: python, function, boolean

I was trying to create a back button in pygame using python but my parameter(condition) is not being set to false, how do I do this?
Here is my code:

```
def back(condition):  #condition - any boolean variable in my script
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if 5 + 125 > mouse[0] > 5 and 5 + 125 > mouse[1] > 5:
        gameDisplay.blit(backBtn, (5, 5))
        if click[0] == 1:
            if condition:
                condition = False
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(backBtn_hover, (5, 5))
```

If you have any sort of answer please answer.

**Thank you! :D**

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you want to set `condition` to be by default `False` ?

Comment: I wanted condition to be a parameter that takes in a boolean variable and only set condition to false when the back button is clicked

Comment: So what is the problem, what's not working in your example? It sounds very simple.

Comment: When the back button is pressed, the condition should be set to false. This is the kind of functionality I want but it the condition is not automaticly being set to false by itself. If its impossible to set the condition to false, I will have to create an individual button for every menu in my game.

Comment: use a class with an instance member `condition` (`self.condition`). Give it a better name.

Comment: function parameters are passed by value for simple types like bool and numbers and by *const* reference for strings (non mutable object)

Answer (score 0):

Since `condition` is of an immutable type, any change to it is only visible inside the function.

You will need to return it and assign it back when calling the function.

```
def back(condition):  #condition - any boolean variable in my script
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if 5 + 125 > mouse[0] > 5 and 5 + 125 > mouse[1] > 5:
        gameDisplay.blit(backBtn, (5, 5))
        if click[0] == 1:
            if condition:
                condition = False
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(backBtn_hover, (5, 5))
    return condition

...

condition = back(condition)
```

It is usually **not** advisable to make it a global variable so I'm not going to suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect this to happen?

```
condition = True
back(condition)
print(condition) # False
```

That's not how Python works. You can't change variables passed to functions. Something like that would work.

```
container = { 'condition': True }
back(container)
print(container['condition']) # False
```

Because in this case you don't change the variable, but its content. But anyway it's bad code. Normally you would do something like that:

```
condition = True
condition = back(condition)
print(condition) # False
```

Of course you need to add a return statement to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer likely is due to scoping of your variables, three examples provided below that hopefully will lead you to a solution:

**Situation 1**

```
condition = True

def back(condition):
    condition = False
    print(f"{condition=}")


def main():
    local_condition = back(condition)
    global_condition = condition
    print(f"{local_condition=}\n{global_condition=}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Results:**

```
condition=False
local_condition=None
global_condition=True
```

**Situation 2 with added return in back funciton**

```
condition = True

def back(condition):
    condition = False
    print(f"{condition=}")
    return condition

def main():
    local_condition = back(condition)
    global_condition = condition
    print(f"{local_condition=}\n{global_condition=}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Results 2:**

```
condition=False
local_condition=False
global_condition=True
```

**Situation 3 redefining global**

```
condition = True

def back(condition):
    condition = False
    print(f"{condition=}")
    return condition

def main():
    global condition
    condition = back(condition)
    global_condition = condition
    print(f"{condition=}\n{global_condition=}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results 3:

```
condition=False
condition=False
global_condition=False
```